# Umbraco - Menu always loads to route #/content after any menu click

Tags: angularjs, umbraco7

I have just updated my site to latest version I have been notified about.
I have following issue:

Clicking on any link in menu in admin site (/umbraco)

The workaround I have found is

- click on the link
- click on profile
- click edit
- confirm that you want to leave the page
- then the page reloads to correct page 
  or
- I can reload manually by typing lets say
  /#settings and the the angular routing does work

Now ever it is annoying and I cannot give it to anyone else to use like this.

Comment: What version have you upgraded to/from? 6 to 7 or just a minor version update? To clarify, when you click the 'Settings' or 'Developer' tabs the url remains at /#content? Could you please open the browser dev tools and check for script errors & missing resources (are an JS references failing to load?).

Comment: @Anth12 yes, its stuck on the same screen. there are no issues in console. reported. I am currently replacing all js files & hope that will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, 
After few days investigation, I have copied all resources from my local pc to the server and to my surprise It works now.

This leads me to the following conclusion:
My project from which I have deployed my versions did not contain all the required files even if all the scripts successfully completed.

If you have same issue, copy all folder to the deployment location and this should do the trick.